# Instantiate a DbContext in IntegrationTests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In the WebApi (.NET Core 2.0 + EF Core) project in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"]));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The Context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public MyContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

No problem when I call the WebApi.

But in my integration test, I'd like do this :

```
[Fact]
void TestMethod()
{
    var context = new MyContext();

    var service = new MyService(context);

    var result = service.GetAll();//Error here

    Assert.True(result.Count() > 0);
}
```

I get this error :

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by  using AddDbContext on the application service provider

How can I instantiate the context and specify the connectionstring to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context still needs to get the connection string and configuration while your default constructor bypasses all of that.

First get rid of the default constructor in your Db context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Next update the test to take advantage of the already provided configuration functionality

```
[Fact]
void TestMethod() {
    //Arrange
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection string here");

    using (var context = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options)) {
        var service = new MyService(context);

        //Act
        var result = service.GetAll();//Error here

        //Assert
        Assert.True(result.Count() > 0);
    }
}
```

Reference [Configuring a DbContext: Configuring DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions)